# cannot open source file of TCP/IP in VS2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, tcp

I'm trying to include that's header file but i got error:"cannot open source file":

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

help someone?
thanks

Comment: Does it say which source file cannot be opened ? Which compiler do you use ? Actually these header files are used on unix/linux like systems. On Windows it's quite different.

Comment: there is a option to use on windows? @MichaelWalz

Comment: I don't know, it's just quite different on Windows.